# How to get Devise reset password link to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

Running Rails 6 on Heroku but have same problem on localhost. When the devise reset password link gets sent it has an address of
...
https://url9208.domain.org/ls/click?upn=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...

That 'url9208' before the domain doesn't go anywhere. How do I make this work? Or how do I get rid of the url9208 part or is that suppose to be there?

Comment: See it this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10694135/7009747

Comment: This example is the opposite of what I want. This solution shows you how to send on subdomains. I don't have subdomains in my app and yet devise is trying to send on subdomains! crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use SendGrid.. You can try to turn off [click tracking](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/tracking#click-tracking) to get rid of the url9208. When it is on, SendGrid overwrites the links in your email template and adds a subdomain.

I had an issue because the SSL certificate didn't cover such a subdomain that was added to password reset links. Turning off click tracking worked in my case.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you Lukas. Had been pulling my hair out for days!!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that this was helpful!